# _tkinter.TclError: when I click on an item from the listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am creating a simple GUI application to manage unknown words while learning a new language (the app is called Vocabulary). The application loads/saves words from/into an XML document.

Nevertheless, I have a listbox:

```
self.listBox = Listbox(self.master,
                       selectmode='extended',
                       height = 34,
                       width = 38)
self.listBox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 7, sticky = W)
self.listBox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.selectedIndexChanged)
```

...with three items in it:

[image: Vocabulary]

To accomplish what I want the application to do, I know that I should handle the selected index changed event, and here is how I did that:

```
def selectedIndexChanged(self, event = None):

    selected = self.listBox.curselection()

    if len(selected) == 0:
        return

    word = self.words[selected[0]]
    self.clear_all()

    self.txt_WordOrPhrase.insert(END, word.wordorphrase)
    self.txt_Explanation.insert(END, word.explanation)
    self.txt_Translation.insert(END, word.translation)
    self.txt_Example.insert(END, word.example)
```

When I click on an item (word) from the listbox, each of its attributes should be displayed in corresponding text widgets. But the problem is that I am getting:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py Exception in Tkinter callback

 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)   File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py", line 264, in
 selectedIndexChanged
     self.txt_WordOrPhrase.insert(END, word.wordorphrase)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3121, in insert
     self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
 _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".140540577622616 insert index chars ?tagList chars tagList ...?"
```

What did I do wrong?

Here is what I have done:

```
# Vocabulary.py
# GUI program to manage unknown words

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os


class Word:

    def __init__(self, wordorphrase = None, explanation = None, translation = None, example = None):
        self.wordorphrase = wordorphrase
        self.explanation = explanation
        self.example = example
        self.translation = translation

class Vocabulary(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self.master.title('Vocabulary')
        self.create_widgets()
        self.words = []
        self.load_words()

    def on_closing(self):

        self.save_all()

        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            self.master.destroy()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.buttons_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.buttons_frame.grid(row = 10, sticky = W)

        self.search_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.search_frame.grid(row = 1, sticky = W, columnspan = 2)

        self.comboBox = ttk.Combobox(self.search_frame,
                                     width = 3)
        self.comboBox.grid(row = 0, column = 14, sticky = W)
        self.comboBox['values'] = ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' )

        self.btn_Add = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                              text = 'Add',
                              command = self.add_item)
        self.btn_Add.grid(row = 0, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Remove = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                                 text = 'Remove',
                                 command = self.remove_item)

        self.btn_Remove.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Edit = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Edit',
                               command = self.edit_item)
        self.btn_Edit.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Save = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Save',
                               command = self.save_item)
        self.btn_Save.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Refresh = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                                  text = 'Refresh',
                                  command = self.refresh_all)
        self.btn_Refresh.grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = W)

        self.lblSearch = Label(self.search_frame, text = 'SEARCH: ')
        self.lblSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 5, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Search = Text(self.search_frame,
                               height = 1,
                               width = 70)
        self.txt_Search.grid(row = 0, column = 6, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)

        self.lblWordsOrPhrases = Label(self.master, text = 'WORDS/PHRASES:')
        self.lblWordsOrPhrases.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.lblWordOrPhrase = Label(self.master, text = 'Word or phrase:')
        self.lblWordOrPhrase.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.listBox = Listbox(self.master,
                               selectmode='extended',
                               height = 34,
                               width = 38)
        self.listBox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 7, sticky = W)
        self.listBox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.selectedIndexChanged)

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase = Text(self.master,
                                     height = 1,
                                     width = 40)
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExplanation = Label(self.master, text = 'Explanation:')
        self.lblExplanation.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Explanation = Text(self.master,
                                    height = 10,
                                    width = 40)
        self.txt_Explanation.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblTranslation = Label(self.master, text = 'Translation:')
        self.lblTranslation.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Translation = Text(self.master,
                                    height = 10,
                                    width = 40)
        self.txt_Translation.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExamples = Label(self.master, text = 'Example(s):')
        self.lblExamples.grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Example = Text(self.master,
                                height = 10,
                                width = 40)
        self.txt_Example.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = S)

    def load_words(self):

        self.listBox.delete(0, END)
        self.words.clear()

        path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
        vocabulary = os.path.join(path, 'Vocabulary', 'Words.xml')

        if not os.path.exists(vocabulary):
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(vocabulary)):
                os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(vocabulary))
            doc = ET.Element('Words')
            tree = ET.ElementTree(doc)
            tree.write(vocabulary)
        else:
            tree = ET.ElementTree(file=vocabulary)

        for node in tree.findall('WordOrPhrase'):
            w = Word(node.find('Word').text, node.find('Explanation').text, node.find('Translation').text,
                     node.find('Examples').text)

            self.words.append(w)
            self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)

    def save_all(self):

        path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
        vocabulary = os.path.join(path, 'Vocabulary', 'Words.xml')

        tree = ET.ElementTree(file=vocabulary)

        for xNode in tree.getroot().findall('WordOrPhrase'):
            tree.getroot().remove(xNode)

        for w in self.words:
            xTop = ET.Element('WordOrPhrase')
            xWord = ET.Element('Word')
            xExplanation = ET.Element('Explanation')
            xTranslation = ET.Element('Translation')
            xExamples = ET.Element('Examples')

            xWord.text = w.wordorphrase
            xExplanation.text = w.explanation
            xTranslation.text = w.translation
            xExamples.text = w.example

            xTop.append(xWord)
            xTop.append(xExplanation)
            xTop.append(xTranslation)
            xTop.append(xExamples)

            tree.getroot().append(xTop)

        tree.write(vocabulary)

    def add_item(self):

        w = Word(self.get_word(), self.get_explanation(), self.get_translation(), self.get_example())

        self.words.append(w)

        self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)

        self.clear_all()

        self.save_all()

    def remove_item(self):
        for index in reversed(self.listBox.curselection()):
            self.listBox.delete(index)
            del self.words[index]

    def edit_item(self):

        if len(self.listBox.curselection()) > 0:
            self.read_only_OFF()

        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Nothing is selected!", "Notification")
            self.btn_Edit.config(state = 'normal')
            self.read_only_ON()

        self.sync()


    def save_item(self):

        if len(self.listBox.curselection()) > 0:
            word = self.find_word(self.listBox.selection.get())
            word.wordorphrase = self.get_word()
            word.explanation = self.get_explanation()
            word.translation = self.get_translation()
            word.example = self.get_example()

            index = self.listBox.index('active')
            self.listBox.delete(index)
            self.listBox.insert(index, self.get_word())
            self.listBox.select_set(index)

    def sync(self):
        pass

    def clear_all(self):
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Explanation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Translation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Example.delete('1.0', END)

    def refresh_all(self):
        self.clear_all()
        self.read_only_OFF()
        self.btn_Edit.config(state = 'disabled')
        self.word_count()
        self.sync()

    def get_word(self):
        return self.txt_WordOrPhrase.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_explanation(self):
        return self.txt_Explanation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_translation(self):
        return self.txt_Translation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_example(self):
        return self.txt_Example.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def find_word(self, word):
        for x in self.words:
            if x.wordorphrase == word:
                return x

    def selectedIndexChanged(self, event = None):

        selected = self.listBox.curselection()

        if len(selected) == 0:
            return

        word = self.words[selected[0]]
        self.clear_all()

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.insert(END, word.wordorphrase)
        self.txt_Explanation.insert(END, word.explanation)
        self.txt_Translation.insert(END, word.translation)
        self.txt_Example.insert(END, word.example)

    def read_only_ON(self):

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.config(state = 'disabled')
        self.txt_Explanation.config(state = 'disabled')
        self.txt_Translation.config(state = 'disabled')
        self.txt_Example.config(state = 'disabled')

    def read_only_OFF(self):

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.config(state = 'normal')
        self.txt_Explanation.config(state = 'normal')
        self.txt_Translation.config(state = 'normal')
        self.txt_Example.config(state = 'normal')


def main():
    root = Tk()
    gui = Vocabulary(root)
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', gui.on_closing)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what is `word.wordorphrase` in this exact case? Is it an object? A list? A string?

Comment: It's an object.

Comment: I will edit the question to include my entire code so you can see what is what.

Comment: Please don't post your entire code. Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you say that `word.wordorphrase` is an object. You can't insert objects in to a listbox.  You can only insert strings.